# Maven repository inheritance: overwriting or merging?

Tags: maven

My Maven project uses the Spring Boot .pom as its parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

According to the Maven guide [Introduction to the POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance),

> Elements in the POM that are merged are the following:
>
> - dependencies
> - developers and contributors
> - plugin lists (including reports)
> - plugin executions with matching ids
> - plugin configuration
> - resources

I have my own local repository configured for this project (which only contains one jar):

```
<repositories>
    <!--other repositories if any-->
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

So if repositories aren't in the list of "elements in the POM that are merged," why does my build work properly? My repo only contains one jar yet I depend on more than that, so if my repository definition was fully "masking" the repository definition of my parent, I don't think the build would work. I assume that because I have specified a parent, I am not also specifying the Super POM as a parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html) you are always getting the standard set of repositories from SuperPOM in any case (at the end it is inherited by your parent pom or its parent pom etc) and repositories are not masked.

If you dont want to use central repository you should create mirror in your settings.xml

```
$MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml
```

like this

```
<mirror>
 <id>internal-repository</id>
 <name>Maven Repository Manager running on repo.mycompany.com</name>
 <url>http://repo.mycompany.com/proxy</url>
 <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

Comment: When inheriting from a parent POM, how do we know which elements are merged (i.e. the actual value in the child is the union of the parent values and the child values) vs which are clobbered (i.e. if the child specifies a value, it overrides the parent value)?

Comment: You can see the final pom with effective pom maven help:effective-pom. You can also override the repository definition by putting id of "central".